# (re)open a specific activity from stack

Tags: android, android-activity, stack

Is there a possibility to reopen a specific activity from the stack?
So say I open activity a, then b, then c. I do not finish a and b while starting new activities. If a push my back-button without overriding it, I would go to B now of course.

But I want to give a button or maybe the back button to open A, or B independent from its location in the stack. This is kind of achievable by finishing the activities (if I would finish b, and press back button from C, I would go to A). But some of my activities I'd rather not finish.

I researched but could not find how to achieve this. Is this possible?

Of course there would be a check needed if the activity is active, and if it is then reopen it or else open it.

Comment: `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT  ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will obviously have to figure out what logic you want to know which `Activity` to open but this should achieve what you are looking for

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    super.onBackPressed();
    Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, ActivityYouWant.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Let me know if this isn't what you were looking for.

[Flag](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT)

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm. No idea how i could have missed this is my research, but this was exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: `Intents` have quite a bit to them which makes it easy to overlook things until you work with them more. Glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

the way ***codeMagic*** suggested you may produce more Activities in the Activity stack then you need. This may leed to **Memory Leaks** or other bad behavior.
you should take a look at:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

or even better `finish()` your `Activities`.